# Sending data to kinesis stream (in different AWS account) using lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-kinesis

I have a lambda function that writes to a kinesis stream. But now, I want to write to a kinesis stream which belongs to a different AWS account. Assuming I have all the necessary cross account permissions, how can I send data to this stream? How should I change the parameters when I call the kinesis constructor or the putRecord function?

Answer (score 4):

There is the method above which would technically work, however hardcoding creds or even configuring creds into a lambda seems a bit extraneous to me since lambdas themselves require that you have a role. What you need to do is create a cross account trust and assume role using sts.

Create a role in the account with the kinesis stream, and set it to trust your lambda role.

Give that role a policy that allows it to put to the kinesis stream.

In your lambda code use sts to create a session in the account with the kinesis stream and put your record.

Note your lambda will need a policy that allows it to sts into the second account's role.

It is described a bit more clearly here  [Providing Access to Accounts you Own](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_aws-accounts.html)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to configure the Kinesis instance:

(I chose Javascript for the example)

```js
var kinesis = new AWS.Kinesis({
    accessKeyId: 'XXX',
    secretAccessKey: 'YYY',
    region: 'eu-west-1',
    apiVersion: '2013-12-02'
});
```

For more informations take a look [Constructing a Kinesis object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Kinesis.html#constructor-property)

To write/put a record use the following

```js
var params = {
    Data: new Buffer('...') || 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
    PartitionKey: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
    StreamName: 'STRING_VALUE', /* required */
    ExplicitHashKey: 'STRING_VALUE',
    SequenceNumberForOrdering: 'STRING_VALUE'
};
kinesis.putRecord(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
    else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

For more informations take a look [Calling the putRecord operation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Kinesis.html#putRecord-property)