# how to publish result of a Lambda Function to a cross-account Kinesis Stream

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam, amazon-kinesis

Say I have two accounts `111111111111` and `222222222222` and want to do following.

```
  (Lambda)   ->  (Kinesis)
111111111111     222222222222
```

Where Lambda function is a trigger for a data source (could be another Kinesis stream in `111111111111`).

```
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {

  // data transformed here
  const result = event.records.map(record => {});

  return {data: result};
}
```

I am trying to format the data in `111111111111`'s Lambda Function and then send it to `22222222222`'s Kinesis stream, but I couldn't find many resources on this.

I came across this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44694309/sending-data-to-kinesis-stream-in-different-aws-account-using-lambda-function). IAM role aside, it seems like each invocation of the Lambda Function needs to create a session with `22222222222` account and creates a Kinesis instance in order to call `PutRecord`. This looks like a red flag to me as I was thinking Lambda function could just set up a cross-account destination with resourceArn to send its result data to. What am I missing and is there better alternate to doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This looks like a red flag to me as I was thinking Lambda function could just set up a cross-account destination with resourceArn to send its result data to.

This is not a red flag. The **cross-account IAM roles** is how it is done for kinesis, because kinesis streams don't have resource-based policies. So you have to assume IAM role from account 2, in your lambda.

I'm not sure which `resourceArn` are you referring to. The only one I can think of is [resourceArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-kinesisanalyticsv2-application-inputlambdaprocessor.html) for Kinesis Data Analytics. This does not apply to Kinesis Data Streams.

Comment: Ok so account 2 needs to trust/assume role account 1's Lambda function's execution role, and account 1 execution role needs to add assume role for account 2. Is this correct?

Comment: sorry. resourceArn was something I made up. I've seen Lambda destinations where you just specify arn for a sns queue, so I wasn't sure if arn for a  kinesis stream is a thing.

Comment: @夢のの夢 SNS and SQS support resource-based policies. As i wrote in the answer, kinesis streams do not.